# Reviewing Apple app before uploading to AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

Hellow.
Sometimes happens that after uploading app to AppStore Apple rejects the app after reviewing and send me a message with errors and warnings. The problem is that after sending app to appstore and before receiving errors several days can be passed.
Is there way to send app to the review but not sending on appstore, then fix probable errors and then send correct app to the appstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the manual release option for the app while pushing it for review. So your app will not be released until you approve.

[image]